# WiredTiger storage engine cause delay in MongoDB start

Tags: mongodb

I'm testing MongoDB (community edition) upgrade from 2.6 to 3.6 (version 3.6.5 is installed) in my company. It's running on Debian Jessie on AWS EC2.
We are experiencing some strange behavior (or maybe it's normal): when we are using WiredTiger storage engine on Mongo 3.6 - between mongo service start and time when it starts to listen for connections there's like 2 minutes delay (depends on disk type attached). 
With Mmapv1 storage engine it's starting to listen for connections immediately.
Database has more than 16k collections with very different numbers of documents in them (from few to tens of thousands), database size with compression enabled is around 4,5 GB, without compression ~11GB

Server on which it's experienced is AWS EC2 instance c4.xlarge (4 cores, 8GB of RAM), I've tried different volumes type attached - magnetic (here startup time was even 4-5 minutes), gp2 (300/3000 IOPS), io1 (with IOPS on 1000 level).
There was no significant difference in startup time between having database files on gp2 or io1 volume (volumes created from scratch not from snapshots so AWS disk warm up is not a case here).
Most of the startup time is spent on WT checkpoint, from mongod.log:

```
2018-07-18T13:25:11.119+0200 D STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] starting WTCheckpointThread thread
2018-07-18T13:26:11.418+0200 D STORAGE  [initandlisten] Slow WT transaction. Lifetime of SnapshotId 1 was 60259ms
```

No matter if filesystem type is EXT3 or XFS, filesystem is mounted with or without noatime option, transparent huge pages disabled or enabled , readahead disabled or enabled - it's always between 60s - 120s (or sometimes more).
I've also tried with separated directory for WiredTiger indexes option but it didn't speed up.
We have database journaling disabled, no replica set in place during tests (but on production replication will be in place).

Any idea if there's anything else I could try? or maybe it's normal behavior, from startup observation I noticed that during WT checkpoint it access each collection file (around ~16k files) so I guess that's where startup is mostly delayed.

Is such startup delay normal with WiredTiger or maybe I missed something?

Comment: From what you described it appears that WT is doing some recovery work e.g. replaying journals or similar. Please post the logs where you see it was accessing each collection file, there may be some hints there.

Comment: Hey, thank you, see log here [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/h2C4s1DX). In places where there's [...] - there is each collection and index touched during start. Also I've noticed Mongo is 'opening' each collection file by using strace tool to monitor process activity.

Comment: What I can immediately see in the logs are two warnings: using XFS, and transparent hugepage. Ext4 is known to stall during checkpoint: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18314 and transparent hugepage can lead to similar issue. Could you resolve the two warnings and see if the stall gets better? There are more recommendations in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/ that you should follow as well.

Comment: Also, disabling journaling on WT doesn't have the benefit that it normally has. In a replica set, it will actually slow down WT since it needs to ensure that the oplog is persisted. In a standalone, it is different, but I usually don't see the benefit in disabling journaling.

Comment: What I also see is this line in the log: `done repairDatabases`. This is not typical. Could you show the output of `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` and the contents of any config file?

Comment: I am exactly at the same point - were you able to solve this problem ?